# How to properly treat siblings nodes with specific comportement on first one

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Hello and thanks for you time reading and helping.

I'm starting to have good knowledge on how XSLT 1.0 process XML but I can't figure this one yet.

My problem is that I have a template matching a first node and applying templates selecting siblings which are treated in a second one but I end up with siblings nodes treated two times.

```
<xsl:template match="/Publication/QuestionReponse[1]">
<div class="bloc_Question">
  <h5 id="titre_Question" class="mb-0">
    Questions ? Réponses !
  </h5>
  <xsl:variable name="lien" select="@URL"/>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="a_extra" href="{$lien}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </a>
    </li>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::QuestionReponse"/>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And another template which XSLT should use on sibling:

```
<xsl:template match="QuestionReponse">
<xsl:variable name="lien" select="@URL"/>
<li>
  <a class="a_extra" href="{$lien}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </a>
</li>
```

With following simplified XML structure:

```
<Publication>
 <QuestionReponse>
  Question1
 </QuestionReponse>
 <QuestionReponse>
  Question2
 </QuestionReponse>
 ...
</Publication>
```

This is working and creating a list with all my wanted node's content.

The problem is my "QuestionReponse" nodes (exept first one which got it's own template) are matched twice and so in my html I end up with following structure :

```
<div>
 <ul>
  <li>
   Question1
  </li>
  <li>
  Question2
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
 <li>
  Question2
 </li>
```

**So I don't understand why XSLT pass a second time in my already processed node, Is there a way to tell XSLT to flag node as treated in my second template ? I guess the problem is XSLT enter my first template then my second (by an non "natural" way) so the node is not "treated" for XSLT and then after all that come back during general recursive processing and treat them again.**

Am I badly implementing this ? Is there no way but to use modes and call-template ? Any advice is welcome.

My full XSL is (concerned part is at the end):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="iso-8859-1" indent="no"/>
  <!-- Overiding Built-In Template -->
  <xsl:template match="text() | @*"/>
  <!-- -->
  <xsl:template match ="/">
    <head>
      <title>
      </title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
      </script>
      <script src="/js/tether.min.js">
      </script>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,300i,400" rel="stylesheet"/>
      <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css"/>
      <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js">
      </script>
      <script src="/js/fonctions.js">
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="main_container" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- ============ General Component Templates ============== -->
  <!-- Fil D'Arianne -->
  <xsl:template match="FilDAriane">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="fildariane">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="FilDAriane/Niveau">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="position()=2">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item">
          <a href="arborescence.html" class="breadcrumb-inactive">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </a>
        </li>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="last()-1 = position()">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </li>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:variable name="ID" select="@ID"/>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item">
          <a href="{$ID}.html" class="breadcrumb-inactive">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </a>
        </li>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- Paragraphe -->
  <xsl:template match="Paragraphe">
    <p>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- Liste -->
  <xsl:template match="Liste[@type='puce']">
    <ul>
      <xsl:for-each select="Item">
        <li>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </li>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- ANoter -->
  <xsl:template match="ANoter">
    <div class="anoter">
      <p class="titre_anoter">
        <img class="img_anoter" src="../img/anoter.svg"></img>
        <strong>
          <xsl:value-of select="Titre"/>
          :
        </strong>
      </p>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- Titre de Fiche -->
  <xsl:template match="/Publication/dc:title">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="title">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- Attention -->
  <xsl:template match="Attention">
    <div class="attention">
      <p class="titre_attention">
        <img class="img_attention" src="../img/warning.svg"></img>
        <strong>
          <xsl:value-of select="Titre"/>
          :
        </strong>
      </p>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- ASavoir -->
  <xsl:template match="ASavoir">
    <div class="asavoir">
      <p class="titre_asavoir">
        <img class="img_asavoir" src="../img/asavoir.svg"></img>
        <strong>
          <xsl:value-of select="Titre"/>
          :
        </strong>
      </p>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- LienInterne -->
  <xsl:template match="LienInterne">
    <xsl:variable name="lien" select="@LienPublication"/>
    <xsl:variable name="type" select="@type"/>
    <a class="lieninterne" title="Aller vers {$type}" alt="{$type}" href="/html/{$lien}.html">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </a>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- LienIntra -->
  <xsl:template match="LienIntra">
    <xsl:variable name="lien" select="@LienID"/>
    <xsl:variable name="type" select="@type"/>
    <a class="lienintra" title="Aller vers {$type}" alt="{$type}" href="/html/{$lien}.html">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </a>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- Service en Ligne -->
  <xsl:template match="ServiceEnLigne">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="service_en_ligne">
        <div id="row_1_service" class="row">
          <div id="col_svg_service" class="col-1">
            <!-- TODO virer le svg en dur -->
            <svg id="icon-document" viewBox="0 0 1334 1024" width="100%" height="100%">
              <title>document</title>
              <path class="color-9" d="M826.18 18.050h-673.263c-64.399 0-117.090 52.69-117.090 117.090v731.809c0 64.399 52.69 117.090 117.090 117.090h673.263c64.399 0 117.090-52.69 117.090-117.090v-731.809c0-64.399-52.69-117.090-117.090-117.090z"></path>
              <path class="color-39" d="M738.363 281.502h-526.903c-17.563 0-29.272 11.708-29.272 29.272s11.708 29.272 29.272 29.272h526.903c17.563 0 29.272-11.708 29.272-29.272s-11.708-29.272-29.272-29.272z"></path>
              <path class="color-39" d="M562.731 457.137h-351.268c-17.563 0-29.272 11.708-29.272 29.272s11.708 29.272 29.272 29.272h351.268c17.563 0 29.276-11.708 29.276-29.272s-11.708-29.272-29.276-29.272z"></path>
              <path class="color-39" d="M416.368 632.77h-204.906c-17.563 0-29.272 11.708-29.272 29.272s11.708 29.276 29.272 29.276h204.906c17.563 0 29.276-11.708 29.276-29.276s-11.708-29.272-29.276-29.272z"></path>
              <path class="color-accent" d="M627.129 600.568l84.89 84.89 424.449-424.449-84.89-84.89-424.449 424.449zM1180.375 47.32l-84.89 84.89 84.89 84.89 84.89-84.89-84.89-84.89zM562.731 749.859l108.308-23.418-81.963-81.963-26.344 105.38z"></path>
            </svg>
          </div>
          <div id="container_cerfa" class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              <p class="service_type">
                <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <h5 class="service_titre">
                <xsl:value-of select="./Titre"/>
              </h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <xsl:if test="@numerocerfa">
          <p class="service_duo_cerfa_intro">
            <p class="service_cerfa">
              <strong>
                Cerfa n°<xsl:value-of select="@numerocerfa"/>
              </strong>
            </p>
            <p class="service_introduction">
              <xsl:value-of select="./Introduction/Texte/Paragraphe"/>
            </p>
          </p>
        </xsl:if>
        <div class="service_p_btn">
          <xsl:variable name="lien" select="@URL"/>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
            <a class="btn_link" href="{$lien}">
              Accéder au formulaire
            </a>
          </button>
          <p class="service_source">
            <xsl:value-of select="./Source"/>
          </p>
        </div>
        <xsl:if test="./NoticeLiee">
          <div id="row_service_notice_texte" class="row">
            <p>
              <strong>
                Pour vous aider à remplir le formulaire :
              </strong>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div id="row_service_notice_lien" class="row">
            <xsl:variable name="lien2" select="@URL"/>
            <p>
              <a class="link_service" href="{$lien2}">
                <xsl:value-of select="./NoticeLiee"/>
              </a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </xsl:if>
      </div>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/Publication/QuestionReponse[1]">
    <div class="bloc_Question">
      <h5 id="titre_Question" class="mb-0">
        Questions ? Réponses !
      </h5>
      <xsl:variable name="lien" select="@URL"/>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a class="a_extra" href="{$lien}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </a>
        </li>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::QuestionReponse"/>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="QuestionReponse">
    <xsl:variable name="lien" select="@URL"/>
    <li>
      <a class="a_extra" href="{$lien}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </a>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- EndOf General Component Templates -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My full XML is (concerned nodes are at the end):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Publication xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ID="F1567" type="Fiche Question-réponse" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../Schemas/3.0/Publication.xsd">
<dc:title>Un mineur peut-il porter plainte seul ?</dc:title>
<dc:creator>Direction de l'information légale et administrative</dc:creator>
<dc:subject>Justice</dc:subject>
<dc:description>Oui, un mineur peut se rendre seul à la police ou à la gendarmerie pour signaler une infraction. Mais il ne peut pas se porter seul partie civile</dc:description>
<dc:publisher>Direction de l'information légale et administrative</dc:publisher>
<dc:contributor>Direction de l'information légale et administrative (Premier ministre), Ministère chargé de la justice</dc:contributor>
<dc:date>modified 2017-07-13</dc:date>
<dc:type>Question-réponse</dc:type>
<dc:format>text/xml</dc:format>
<dc:identifier>F1567</dc:identifier>
<dc:source>http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCode.do?idSectionTA=LEGISCTA000024458641&amp;cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006071154</dc:source>
<dc:language>Fr</dc:language>
<dc:relation>isPartOf N260</dc:relation>
<dc:coverage>France entière</dc:coverage>
<dc:rights>https://www.service-public.fr/a-propos/mentions-legales</dc:rights>
<SurTitre>Question-réponse</SurTitre>
<Audience>Particuliers</Audience>
<Canal>www.service-public.fr</Canal>
<FilDAriane>
<Niveau ID="Particuliers">Accueil particuliers</Niveau>
<Niveau ID="N19807">Justice</Niveau>
<Niveau ID="N260">Mineur victime</Niveau>
<Niveau ID="F1567" type="Fiche Question-réponse">Un mineur peut-il porter plainte seul ?</Niveau>
</FilDAriane>
<Theme ID="N19807">
<Titre>Justice</Titre>
</Theme>
<SousThemePere ID="N20279">Justice des mineurs</SousThemePere><DossierPere ID="N260">
<Titre>Mineur victime</Titre>
<Fiche ID="F20283">Vol ou racket</Fiche>
<Fiche ID="F952">Mauvais traitements</Fiche>
<Fiche ID="F2274">Infraction sexuelle</Fiche>
<Fiche ID="F2532">Prostitution infantile</Fiche>
<Fiche ID="F31985">Harcèlement à l'école</Fiche>
</DossierPere>

<Texte><Paragraphe>Un mineur victime d'une infraction peut <LienInterne LienPublication="F1435" type="Fiche d'information" audience="Particuliers">porter plainte</LienInterne> lui-même en écrivant au procureur ou en se rendant (seul ou accompagné) dans les locaux de la police ou de la gendarmerie.</Paragraphe>
<BlocCas affichage="onglet">
<Cas>
<Titre>
<Paragraphe>Sur place</Paragraphe>
</Titre>
          <Paragraphe>Vous devez vous adresser à un commissariat de police ou une brigade de gendarmerie.</Paragraphe>
          <OuSAdresser ID="R13" type="Local personnalisable">
<Titre>Commissariat ou Gendarmerie</Titre>
<PivotLocal>commissariat_police</PivotLocal>
<RessourceWeb URL="http://www.interieur.gouv.fr/Contact/Contacter-une-brigade-de-gendarmerie-ou-un-commissariat-de-police"/>
</OuSAdresser>

          <Paragraphe>La réception de la plainte ne peut pas vous être refusée.</Paragraphe>
          <Paragraphe>La plainte est ensuite transmise au procureur de la République.</Paragraphe>
          <Paragraphe>Avant de vous rendre au commissariat ou à la gendarmerie, vous pouvez remplir une pré-plainte en ligne si vous êtes victime d'une atteinte aux biens (vol, escroquerie....) dont l'auteur vous est inconnu. Vous obtiendrez alors un rendez-vous et les policiers ou gendarmes auront déjà les éléments de votre plainte à votre arrivée.</Paragraphe>
          <ServiceEnLigne ID="R19620" URL="https://www.pre-plainte-en-ligne.gouv.fr/" numerocerfa="16309*01" autrenumero="16310*01" type="Téléservice">
<Titre>Pré-plainte en ligne</Titre>
<Source ID="R30603">Ministère chargé de l'intérieur</Source>
</ServiceEnLigne>

         
</Cas>
<Cas>
<Titre>
<Paragraphe>Par correspondance</Paragraphe>
</Titre>
          <Paragraphe>Vous devez écrire directement au procureur de la République. Il faut envoyer une <LienInterne LienPublication="R11469" type="Modèle de document" audience="Particuliers">lettre sur papier libre</LienInterne> au tribunal de grande instance du lieu de l'infraction ou du domicile de l'auteur de l'infraction.</Paragraphe>
          <Paragraphe>La lettre doit préciser :</Paragraphe>
          <Liste type="puce">
           <Item>
            <Paragraphe>l'état civil complet du plaignant et ses coordonnées complètes (adresse et numéro de téléphone),</Paragraphe>
           </Item>
           <Item>
            <Paragraphe>le récit détaillé des faits, la date et le lieu de l'infraction,</Paragraphe>
           </Item>
           <Item>
            <Paragraphe>le nom de l'auteur supposé si vous le connaissez (sinon, il convient de déposer plainte contre X),</Paragraphe>
           </Item>
           <Item>
            <Paragraphe>les noms et adresses des éventuels témoins de cette infraction,</Paragraphe>
           </Item>
           <Item>
            <Paragraphe>la description et l'estimation provisoire ou définitive du préjudice,</Paragraphe>
           </Item>
           <Item>
            <Paragraphe>les documents de preuve  : certificats médicaux constatant les blessures, arrêts de travail, factures diverses, constats en cas de dégâts matériels.</Paragraphe>
           </Item>
          </Liste>
         
          <OuSAdresser ID="R30" type="Local personnalisé sur SP">
<Titre>Tribunal de grande instance (TGI)</Titre>
<PivotLocal>tgi</PivotLocal>
<RessourceWeb URL="http://www.annuaires.justice.gouv.fr/annuaires-12162/annuaire-des-tribunaux-de-grande-instance-21768.html"/>
<Source ID="R30663">Ministère chargé de la justice</Source>
</OuSAdresser>

         
          <Paragraphe>Vous pouvez envoyer votre plainte en lettre recommandée avec accusé de réception mais ce n'est pas obligatoire, vous pouvez envoyer une lettre simple. Dans tous les cas, un récépissé vous sera remis dès que le procureur aura enregistré votre plainte.</Paragraphe>
         
</Cas>
</BlocCas>

<Paragraphe>Le mineur peut ainsi signaler toute infraction dont il est victime à la justice. Mais s'il veut être impliqué dans le reste de la procédure, il devra obligatoirement être représenté par une personne majeure.</Paragraphe>
<Paragraphe>Ainsi, si sa plainte donne lieu à des poursuites, le mineur souhaitant obtenir une indemnisation doit <LienInterne LienPublication="F1454" type="Fiche Question-réponse" audience="Particuliers">se constituer partie civile</LienInterne> via des personnes majeures agissant en son nom :</Paragraphe>
<Liste type="puce">
<Item>
<Paragraphe>ses parents (ou ses représentants légaux),</Paragraphe>
</Item>
<Item>
<Paragraphe>ou un <LienExterne URL="http://www.justice.gouv.fr/publication/guide_aah.pdf">administrateur ad hoc</LienExterne>

 désigné par la justice, lorsque les parents du mineur ne peuvent pas défendre ses intérêts. C'est notamment le cas si les parents sont impliqués dans l'infraction, en cas de <LienInterne LienPublication="F952" type="Fiche d'information" audience="Particuliers">maltraitance</LienInterne> par exemple.</Paragraphe>
</Item>
</Liste>
<ANoter>
<Titre>À noter</Titre><Paragraphe>les parents d'un mineur peuvent également porter plainte en son nom, sans besoin d'un accord de l'enfant.</Paragraphe>
</ANoter>
</Texte>
<OuSAdresser ID="R167" type="Centre de contact">
<Titre>08 Victimes</Titre>
<Source ID="R30797">Institut national d'aide aux victimes et de médiation (Inavem)</Source><Texte>
      
        <Paragraphe>
   
      Écoute, informe et conseille les victimes d'infractions ainsi que leurs proches.</Paragraphe>
       
      <Chapitre>
<Titre>
<Paragraphe>Par téléphone</Paragraphe>
</Titre>
        <Paragraphe>
   <MiseEnEvidence>08 842 846 37</MiseEnEvidence>
      depuis la France métropolitaine</Paragraphe>
        <Paragraphe>Ouvert 7 jours sur 7 de 9h à 21h</Paragraphe>
        <Paragraphe>Numéro gris ou banalisé : coût d'un appel vers un fixe et service gratuit, depuis un téléphone fixe ou mobile</Paragraphe>
        <Paragraphe>
<MiseEnEvidence>+33 (0)1 41 83 42 08</MiseEnEvidence> depuis l'outre-mer ou l'étranger</Paragraphe>
        <Paragraphe>Ouvert 7 jours sur 7 de 9h à 21h</Paragraphe>
        <Paragraphe>
   Coût d'un appel local depuis un poste fixe</Paragraphe>
       </Chapitre>
      <Chapitre>
<Titre>
<Paragraphe>Par courriel</Paragraphe>
</Titre>
        <Paragraphe>En utilisant le <LienExterne URL="http://www.inavem.org/index.php/component/chronoforms5/?chronoform=contact_victimes">formulaire de contact</LienExterne>
</Paragraphe>
       </Chapitre>
     </Texte>
</OuSAdresser>
<Reference type="Texte de référence" URL="http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCode.do?idSectionTA=LEGISCTA000024458641&amp;cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006071154" ID="R15905">
<Titre>Code de procédure pénale : articles 1 à 10</Titre>
<Complement>Début d'une procédure pénale</Complement>
</Reference>
<ServiceEnLigne ID="R11469" URL="" type="Modèle de document">
<Titre>Porter plainte auprès du procureur de la République</Titre>
<Source ID="R30608">Direction de l'information légale et administrative (Premier ministre)</Source>
</ServiceEnLigne>
<ServiceEnLigne ID="R19620" URL="https://www.pre-plainte-en-ligne.gouv.fr/" numerocerfa="16309*01" autrenumero="16310*01" type="Téléservice">
<Titre>Pré-plainte en ligne</Titre>
<Source ID="R30603">Ministère chargé de l'intérieur</Source>
</ServiceEnLigne>
<PourEnSavoirPlus type="Information pratique" ID="R35961" URL="http://www.interieur.gouv.fr/A-votre-service/Ma-securite/Aide-aux-victimes" audience="Particuliers">
<Titre>Guide des droits des victimes</Titre>
<Source ID="R30603">Ministère chargé de l'intérieur</Source>
</PourEnSavoirPlus>
<PourEnSavoirPlus type="Information pratique" ID="R41472" URL="http://www.justice.gouv.fr/justice-des-mineurs-10042/" audience="Particuliers">
<Titre>La justice des mineurs</Titre>
<Source ID="R30663">Ministère chargé de la justice</Source>
</PourEnSavoirPlus>
<QuestionReponse ID="F1154" audience="Particuliers">Le procureur est-il tenu d'engager des poursuites à la suite d'une plainte ?</QuestionReponse>
<QuestionReponse ID="F16862" audience="Particuliers">Peut-on retirer une plainte et quelles en sont les conséquences ?</QuestionReponse>

</Publication>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this call

```
<xsl:apply-templates/>
```

in the parent context and this call

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::QuestionReponse"/>
```

in the child context. Both process the same `QuestionReponse` nodes, like this:

The first `<xsl:apply-templates/>` works on all children of `/`, because it sits in a template that matches `/` and selects no target.

So it applies to `<Publication>`. There is no template for `<Publication>`. The default behavior for elements that don't have a matching template is `<xsl:apply-templates/>` *as well*, but of course this time all children of `<Publication>` are affected.

The first `<QuestionReponse>` has a special template. This runs, and internally calls `<xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::QuestionReponse"/>`, which processes all the remaining `<QuestionReponse>` elements.

But the higher-level `<xsl:apply-templates/>` cannot know this. It is not finished itself and continues to apply templates to all nodes it has not processed yet. So all the `<QuestionReponse>` elements are processed a second time. Consequence: all the non-first `<QuestionReponse>` children of `<Publication>` show up two times.

---

Resolution: In the parent context, apply templates to all children *except* non-first `<QuestionReponse>` elements:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::QuestionReponse and preceding-sibling::QuestionReponse)]" />
```

There are other ways to express the same thing, but *"is not a `<QuestionReponse>` that has any preceding `<QuestionReponse>`"* is close enough.

The change in behavior is that the higher-level `<xsl:apply-templates/>` now actively excludes elements that are processed separately in a child template.

Comment: Thanks a lot, functional XSLT mess up with my human cognition haha. I could not figure that alone. Thanks again :)

Comment: You can also use template modes, like this: A default template `<xsl:template match="QuestionReponse" />` (it's empty, so there is no output) and then the *actual* template with a mode: `<xsl:template match="QuestionReponse" mode="li"><li>...</li></xsl:template>`. This will not be not executed except when you call it, like `<xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::QuestionReponse" mode="li" />`. Doing it this way you don't need to rewrite the higher-level `<xsl:apply-templates />`, which results in greater flexibility.